# Load another application when entering background

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, multitasking, url-scheme

Is it possible to load up another application when the first application enters the background?

Say I have application 1 and application 2 installed.
When application 1 enters the background, the method is called to invoke the loading of application 2, but application 2 is never loaded.

Is it possible that Apple have disallowed this sort of thing?

I am 100% sure that the custom URL schemes I'm using are able to be called as I have done testing within MobileSafari to make sure they work.

Should mention this is for an iPad application and not iPhone application. Albeit, I don't think there should be much difference between the two when it comes to this issue...

**EDIT**

Let me explain. The application itself is for a specific purpose. What we want to do is allow our clients to set a setting that will allow the application to "bounce" back via another installed application.
We want to limit the users of the application to only be able to use the application in question. This is due to the fact that the iPad's using this application will ONLY be using this application. Hence why we want to lock it down as best we can.

Comment: You don't want to do this, for the sake of your users.

Comment: Check edited section, explains why.

Comment: Yeah people can still turn the iPad off and back on.

Comment: I understand that, but we're just trying to cover this single issue at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work, simply because the application can only have the system open URL schemes while in the foreground. Think of it like this, if your application is not in the foreground can it, say, present a modal view such as a UIAlertView or a simple Modal View Controller?

Also, you would be horribly breaking Human Interface Guidelines and would most likely be rejected. URL schemes, especially custom ones, should only be called when the user prompts.

Comment: Alright then, is it possible to intercept the call of going into the background and fire off another method that in turn opens application 2?

Comment: Also, it wouldn't be all the time, it is only if a setting is defined first.

Comment: You can run a test to double check in your shared UIApplicationDelegate to see. Just try launching a standard URL in `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application`

Comment: Tried launching a standard URL (mailto:) within the method above. Mail.app is not launched. Seems Apple do not want us to do this at all...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you want a lockdown/kiosk iOS system. There's simply no way to do this and make it work like they want without breaking out of apple's sandbox. Jail breaking. Or, write one application with two halves.  The initial half with authentication or whatever, then the secured half. Maybe we need more context, but as you describe it, URL schemes are incredibly easy to circumvent or fail altogether.  What happens when they just delete the goto app?

Comment: Exactly. We're looking for a lockdwon/kisok iOS that only allows our application to run, nothing else. This means that the customer will only be able to view the application in question. Unfortunately you're correct, the only way to do it is jailbreaking or some special swizzling. We're working hard to find the solution.

Comment: Depending on what you want, you might be able to use the parental locks to block out any app but yours, and prevent the installation of new apps. I havent investigated, but that just came to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Now why would you do that? <strike>Say the user is getting a call and he proceeds to take it. He definitely wouldn't want to go to another app in between. Other case considered,</strike> he would actually leave your app to go to another app he wants to attend to without being taken to another app in between.

Comment: The application in question is for a specific target. It runs on the iPad and clients do not want consumers to utilise the iPad's for anything other than application 1's intent.

Comment: So do you want to provide an alternate home screen kind of thing?

Comment: Basically, if in application 1 a setting is defined, then application 2 acts as a sort of "bounce" back to application 1. If the setting isn't defined, then we just pop back to the homescreen.